# Heterogenize numpy array such that no two adjacent cellls are equal

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a large numpy array which I would like to populate using the following criteria:

- use numbers only from a set range (0 to 9) example
- populate such that no adjacent cells are equal. This means that each cell would be surrounded by values which would be different from it. No exceptions can be allowed.

I am currently using the following function

```
def uniqify(in_array):
    #warning: array is mutable and gets modified outside this scope
    out_array = np.arange(in_array.size).reshape(in_array.shape)
    return out_array.astype(np.float32)
```

This, however violates the first criterion since the array values go up to very high numbers. Since I do not know the size of these arrays before I input into this function, I would rather restrict the size of the numbers that can be contained in each entry.

Are there any elegant solutions to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

I am currently looking at some of the randomizing functionalities in numpy such as https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html.

Heres an example I cooked up using `np.random.choice`

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]])
size = np.size(data)

for i in range(20):
    random_list = np.random.choice(size, size, replace= False)/(size-1)
    print(random_list)
print('\ndone')
```

This prints a variety of lists with numbers ranging from 0 to 1, which is fine, however for large datasets I can imagine the difference between possible samples to be so slim as to render them almost equal. I therefore cannot randomize, but need to drive a function with the explicit goal of avoiding that adjacent cells are equal. The numbers could, I imagine draw from 1 to 9...

Comment: With `replace=False` you will never get equal adjacent values, as all values are unique. So assuming your goal is to get a `random_list` that is longer than the number of possible values, why not populate it in a for loop where you keep track of the last added element. If the next choice is equal to the last element, choose another.

Comment: How random do you need your list to be? It is easy to come up with regular "checkerboard" like patterns that satisfy your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

As Paul Panzer commented, a regular checkerboard-like pattern can be constructed:

```
def uniq(shape):
    f = lambda *idx: np.mod(np.sum(idx, axis=0), 10)
    return np.fromfunction(f, shape)
```

For example, `uniq((5, 17))` is

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.]
 [ 3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.  0.]]
```

No adjacent elements are equal. The modulo can be even taken mod 2, resulting in a 0-1 array.

If you want the array to be (or at least look) random, fractional steps can help.

```
def uniq(shape):
    steps = 1 + np.mod(np.random.randint(1, 100, size=len(shape))*(np.sqrt(5)+1)/2, 8)
    f = lambda *idx: np.mod(np.floor(np.random.uniform(0, 10) + np.moveaxis(idx, 0, -1).dot(steps)), 10)
    return np.fromfunction(f, shape)
```

Now `uniq((5, 17))` is something random-looking like

```
[[ 4.  8.  3.  7.  2.  7.  1.  6.  0.  5.  0.  4.  9.  3.  8.  3.  7.]
 [ 0.  4.  9.  4.  8.  3.  7.  2.  7.  1.  6.  0.  5.  0.  4.  9.  3.]
 [ 6.  1.  5.  0.  4.  9.  4.  8.  3.  7.  2.  7.  1.  6.  0.  5.  0.]
 [ 2.  7.  1.  6.  1.  5.  0.  4.  9.  4.  8.  3.  7.  2.  7.  1.  6.]
 [ 8.  3.  8.  2.  7.  1.  6.  1.  5.  0.  4.  9.  4.  8.  3.  7.  2.]]
```

The first version amounts to all steps being 1. The computation of steps is based on the golden ratio `(np.sqrt(5)+1)/2` because its multiples produce uniformly distributed but random-looking numbers. The steps are guaranteed to be between 1 and 9, so with each step, after flooring and taking mod 10, we are assured of having a different number.